# PHP array_slice() - ensuring the last the first and last elements are selected

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I wondering if anyone has a clever way of ensuring the last element of an array is selected during a array_slice operation. The first element is easily selected, but if an offset is applied you cannot be sure the last element is selected unless you add an additional `if else` logic after the loop.

For example here is the basis of the problem without the `if else statement`.

```
$latlong[] = [1,2];
$latlong[] = [3,4];
$latlong[] = [5,6];
$latlong[] = [7,8];
$latlong[] = [9,10];
$latlong[] = [11,12];
$latlong[] = [19,110];
$latlong[] = [21,132];

$off = 3;

for ($i=0; $i < count($latlong); $i+=$off){
    print_r(  array_slice($latlong, $i,1));
}
```

In the example here you will see that only the pairs `[1,2], [7,8], [19,110]` are selected and the last element `[21,132]` would need to be included some other way.

The relevance is to ensure only a certain number of 'waypoints' are selected to stay within a limit, but that the first and last elements are included in that limit.

Comment: For creating chunks of certian length there's `array_chunk`

Comment: So your question is, while slicing if the offset goes over the end of the array you want it to select the last element in the array instead correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, this code works:

```
<?php
$latlong[] = [1,2];
$latlong[] = [3,4];
$latlong[] = [5,6];
$latlong[] = [7,8];
$latlong[] = [9,10];
$latlong[] = [11,12];
$latlong[] = [19,110];
$latlong[] = [21,132];

$off = 3;

for ($i=0; $i < count($latlong); $i+=$off){

    if(count($latlong) - $i <= $off){
        $last_element = end($latlong);
    }
    print_r(  array_slice($latlong, $i,1));
}

print_r($last_element);

?>
```

The ***if*** statement, in that case, verifies if you set any offset on your code, **$last_element** variable always contains the last element of your array.

Comment: Yes, agree.  I think this is the best way of doing it.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other ways like calculating the modulus but this works:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($latlong); $i+=$off){
    $data[] = array_slice($latlong, $i,1);
    $last = $i;
}

var_dump(array_slice($latlong, $last+1));
```

If I add 2 other elements to the array, it will be empty. Also, you might want to take a look at a php variant of pythons xrange().

```
function xrange($start, $end, $step = 1){
  for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += $step){
    yield $i;
  }
}

foreach(xrange(0, count($latlong), $off) as $last){
  $data[] = array_slice($latlong, $last,1);
}

var_dump(array_slice($latlong, $last+1));
```